# combining istanbul coverage reports for integration tests

Tags: integration-testing, code-coverage, istanbul

I have a Node app skeleton (https://github.com/jedwards1211/crater) with integration tests that start the server and run tests using webdriver.io.  I'm not sure how to generate full code coverage because there are three pieces that need to be covered, all running separately:

- The code that builds and spawns the server process
- The code that runs on the server
- The code that runs on the client (i.e. PhantomJS)

I know that I can build all that code using `babel-plugin-istanbul` to instrument it.  And I know it would be easy to run the server with `nyc` and get coverage for only the server code.  But is there any way to get a combined coverage report for all three pieces after running the integration test?

#### What I've found out so far

- It's possible to combine coverage info using: http://gotwarlost.github.io/istanbul/public/apidocs/classes/Collector.html
- I should be able to transport coverage from instrumented code in the browser to the test scripts by running (via webdriver.io):
  `(await browser.execute(() => window.__coverage__)).value`

Comment: You can use a hosted tool to merge all reports while maintaining each individual report integrity via [Codecov](https://codecov.io). http://docs.codecov.io/docs/merging-reports and http://docs.codecov.io/docs/flags do the trick. PS I can provide a detailed answer below is you are cool with a hosted solution.

Comment: @StevePeak well, unfortunately I'm using Coveralls.  But I'll look into it.

Comment: Looks like I'll also be able to merge coverage info with my own code if I want to using Istanbul's `Collector`, before writing reports.